# как запустить dev-server у @symfony/webpack-encore под Homestead в Vagrant?

Tags: javascript, webpack, symfony3, homestead

Пытаюсь поднять Symfony 3 на Homestead в Vagrant. Но не получаю доступ к файлам frontend'а запуская `npm run dev-server`.

Мой webpack.config.js:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
.setOutputPath('web/assets/')
.setPublicPath('/assets')
.cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
.addStyleEntry('css/page1', './assets/page1.scss')
.addStyleEntry('css/cabinet', './assets/cabinet.scss')
.enableSassLoader()
.addEntry('js/assets', './assets/assets_twig.js')
.addEntry('js/cabinet', './cabinet.js')
.enableSourceMaps( ! Encore.isProduction())
.enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

После запуска dev-server я получаю вот такой `manifest.json`:

```
{
  "assets/page1.css": "http://localhost:8080/assets/css/page1.css",
  "assets/cabinet.css": "http://localhost:8080/assets/css/cabinet.css",
  "assets/assets.js": "http://localhost:8080/assets/js/assets.js",
  "assets/cabinet.js": "http://localhost:8080/assets/js/cabinet.js"
}
```

Захожу на `http://site.test` страница загружается, но без статики.

Знаю что дело в `http://localhost:8080` но как это исправить, ума не приложу.
Прошу Вашей помощи, уже 4 часа сижу с Homestead никак не настрою под себя, надеюсь это последняя проблема, хотя БД еще не настроил.

Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: D:\Homestead\.ssh\id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - D:\Homestead\.ssh\id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:\sites
      to: /home/vagrant/sites

sites:
    - map: site.test
      to: /home/vagrant/sites/mysite/web
      type: symfony2

databases:
    - mysite

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перерыл весь пакет `@symfony/webpack-encore` и обнаружил в ней, что у команды `dev-server` есть аргумент `host`
Выполнив команду `./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --host site.test` у меня запустился рабочий фронтенд сборщик без проблем указанных в вопросе.

Команда `npm run dev-server --host site.test` не работала, поэтому в `package.json` я добавил свою команду

```
"dss": "./node_modules/.bin/encore dev-server --host site.test"
```

и с помощью команды `npm run dss` запускаю свой фронтенд сборщик.